# Problems loading Alternative PHP Cache (APC)

Tags: php, apc, linode

I have a VPS hosted by linode running ubunutu 12.04 LTS.  I took a look at my error.log file and it looks like APC isn't loading.

I have

```
extension=apc.so
```

in my php.ini file and I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge php-apc 
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

but that didn't fix it.  Here's the error I'm getting.

```
[28-Mar-2015 10:39:01 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/apc.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I found a copy of the apc.so file here:

```
/usr/lib/php5/20090626/apc.so
```

I tried changing the php.ini file to:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/apc.so
```

and restarted apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but got this error instead

```
[28-Mar-2015 10:56:43 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/apc.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/apc.so: undefined symbol: zend_unmangle_property_name in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Is there a file at that location? What are its permissions? Can you find any similar file using `locate apc.so`?

Comment: @halfer Thanks.  I updated my question.  I did try to locate the apc.so file and found one but pointing to it didn't work.  I haven't checked the permissions.  What permissions of which folder/file?

Comment: The permissions of the file in your error, `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/apc.so`. It's just a thought - maybe the web server cannot see it. I tend to look at permissions on other (working) extensions to see what the perms/ownership should be.